# JQuery ajax function in a for loop is behaving weird

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

"get_ing_id" gets a string, looks to the database and retrieve relevant id data according to the string. At this example, it needs to retrieve '65' and '66' which it does successfully when the code is executed.

```
var ings = [];
var ingsSearch = [];
var i = 2;
var k = 0;
ings[0] = 'apple';
ings[1] = 'banana';

    function next(){
        for(j=0;j<i;j++){
            if(ings[j] != 0){           
                $.ajax({
                    url: burl+'index.php/ajax/get_ing_id',
                    type: 'POST',   
                    data: 'name='+ings[j],
                    success: function(data){    
                        ingsSearch[k] = data;
                        alert(ingsSearch[k]);
                        k++;
                        alert(k);
                    }
                });                     
            }

        }   
    alert(ingsSearch[0]);
    alert(ingsSearch[1]);

    }
```

When the code is executed, I get alert boxes in order:

- 66
- 1
- 65
- 2
- undefined
- undefined

It supposed to be like this

- 66
- 1
- 65
- 2
- 66
- 65

So where am I doing wrong? I'm not very experienced with javascript, I'll be grateful if I get any help. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `async` property of the `ajax` object to `false`. Default is `true` so there is no guarantee the calls will finish sequentially:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    // ..
});
```

- [ajax()<sup>jQuery</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) <-- see `async` property

*Do note ShankarSangoli's comment; the ideal way to code this is not loop-based, but to progress to the next element from the AJAX callback function.*

Comment: damn, this solves a completely unrelated problem that was bothering me for a while now. learnin' something new every day (:

Comment: Setting `async` to false is not adviceable because it will stop the page completely until the server responds. Try to avoid this and use a callback mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to understand that AJAX is, by default, asynchronous - the success function is called as soon as the server responds, which most likely happens after the two `alert` statements are called; so `lngsSearch[0]` `lngsSearch[1]` haven't actually been set when you're trying to output them.